# Adding a button to a GridLayout programatically Android

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-studio

I'm trying to programatically add a button within a GridLayout in Android. This is the code i'm using:

```
public class GridScrollTest extends AppCompatActivity {

private GridLayout gridLayout;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_grid_scroll_test);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            CreateNewItem();

            Snackbar.make(view, "Added a new button", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .setAction("Action", null).show();
        }
    });
}

private void CreateNewItem(){

    gridLayout = (GridLayout)findViewById(R.id.gridLayout);

    Button newButton = new Button(this);
    newButton.getLayoutParams().width = 100;
    newButton.getLayoutParams().height = 140;
    newButton.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL | Gravity.FILL_VERTICAL);
    newButton.requestLayout();

    gridLayout.addView(newButton);
}
```

At the moment the code does nothing. It doesn't crash, but it also doesn't add the button. The "Added a new button" Snackbar is triggered though.

This is what aiming for:

[image: Aim]

A new button would be added next to the previous button, with the button after that been added to the row below. All the buttons would be of the same size (They will later be Image Buttons).

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Why don't you try Recycler view with grid layout? You can just add it to list and notify adapter.

Comment: Thanks, that worked great!